# transaction receipt not working

Tags: web3js, truffle, react

I use react and web3 to interact with metamask.
Until yesterday every thing was fine. but, today some of the transaction results are not returning.
I use this code to load web3

```
let web3
if (window.ethereum) {
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
  await window.ethereum.enable();
  this.setState({web3: web3})
}
else {
  window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
}
```

when I, want to use `send().on('receipt')`... its not returning anything.
but `send().on(transactionHash)`works fine
I have no clue why would `receipt` suddenly stops to work.
here is the code

```
contractInstance.methods.transferOwnership(newOwner).send({from: 
accounts[0]}).on('receipt', function(receipt){
        console.log("events of transfer ownership" , receipt.events)
     })
```

I mean the function works fine and the ownership transfers, but the receipt is not working at all

Comment: I have the same issue with receipt and confirmation events